# Exporting from Jasper to Excel

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am trying to export iReport from jasper to excel but the cells keep changing my data type from number to string. Please can anyone help with xml property to correct this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm no expert for this, but for those who are, I think it would be helpful to add some details and code samples to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of jrxml with definition of fields make question more correct

Check type of $F{yourField} (not java.lang.String).

Set detect cell type in yourReport.jrxml

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ...>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks alot that really worked. if i add the property for csv and xlsx too will it work? like <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.detect.cell.type" value="true"/> and <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>

Comment: CSV contain typed data? Show this file, pls ;)